# Get Day Name from date picker?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get date in this format "Saturday, 6/10/2018" from the Date Picker Dialog. The problem is that when I select any date from current month it displays true output but when I select any date from previous or next month it displays wrong name of day of the week.

Note: Previously asked questions doesn't helped me...

Here is my code:

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pickDateBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:text="Pick Full Date" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/displayDateTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Full Date will display here..."
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> MainActivity.kt

```
package com.blogspot.atifsoftwares.fulldateformat

import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        pickDateBtn.setOnClickListener {
            pickDate()
        }
    }

    private fun pickDate() {
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, mYear, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->

            val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE")
            val date = Date(mYear, month, dayOfMonth - 1)
            val dayString = simpleDateFormat.format(date) //returns true day name for current month only

            displayDateTv.text = "$dayString, $dayOfMonth/${monthOfYear + 1}/$mYear"

        }, year, month, day)
        dpd.show()

    }
}
```

Comment: The three-arg `Date` constructor you are using is deprecated and unreliable. The whole `Date` class is poorly designed. `Calendar` too and `SimpleDateFormat` notoriously troublesome. Consider [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead. To use it on older Android, get [the ThreeTenABP library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, mYear, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->

        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE")
        val date = Date(mYear, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth - 1)
        val dayString = simpleDateFormat.format(date) //returns true day name for current month only

        displayDateTv.text = "$dayString, $dayOfMonth/${monthOfYear + 1}/$mYear"

    }, year, month, day)
```

You were using closure month variable not the one you got in lambda while initializing Date class. Check this edited code.

Answer (score 1):

```
val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, mYear, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->

        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE")
        val date = Date(mYear, month, dayOfMonth - 1)
        val dayString = simpleDateFormat.format(date) //returns true day name for current month only

        displayDateTv.text = "$dayString, $dayOfMonth/${monthOfYear + 1}/$mYear"

    }, year, month, day)
```

Change 
`val date = Date(mYear, month, dayOfMonth - 1)`
to `val date = Date(mYear, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth - 1)`

Explaination : you are using closure month variable not the one you got in lambda while initializing Date class.